# what does slope mean in mathematics ?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need your help. My question is: what does "slope" mean in mathematics?

A clear example would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Rise over run of a function/line. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope

Answer (score 2):

I would sum it up as the rate of change, whether in the sense of derivatives or a linear functions. In other words how fast is the graph increasing (or decreasing if the slope is negative). Consider for instance an object initially resting at $x=b$ moving to the right with velocity $a$. Then at any given time $t$ we would have a position function as
$$
x(t) = ax + b
$$
Now here you can immediately see that the slope is $a$. This describes the rate of change of what this function represents, namely position. As we used above this is exactly what *speed* is considered to be, the rate of change of position.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I will make the clearest example I can.

Take the expression $x^2$ and then graph it. The value of $x^2$ when $x=1$ is 1 and when $x=2$ it is 4. Therefore the rise as Shahar called it is $4-1=3$. The run (again as Shahar called it) between $x=1$ and $x=2$ is $2-1=1$. Hence, the slope of $x^2$ between $x=1$ and $x=2$ is $\dfrac{3}{1} = 3$.

This notion is especially useful for affine ("linear" as some call them) expressions, of the form $ax+b$, because the slope between any two points is always the same (which is $a$ by the way). Usually, in the last year of high school, this is generalized to "curved" expressions like the one I used above, where the slope changes depending on the chosen points, and leads to a set of mathematical tools called calculus.

Answer (score 1):

There are various places you can go for highly technical explanations of what slope means in both its generalized case (derivative) and the more philosophical aspects.
The short answer is rise over run. What this means is that we want to know how much higher the function is if you move over a certain amount to the right. Consider the function y=5x+3. We know that we plot this by starting at the point (0,3). All points that satisfy this equation fit on the line. So if we plug in x=1, then y=8. By continuing this process we end up with a graphed line. 
The slope of this line is the distance "up," (change in y) for every distance we go "right," (change in x). So if we were to go 1 in the x direction (say from 0 to 1) we move up 5. The y=mx+b line form is actually designed to make problems like this easier.
Now suppose we had something more complicated, like $y=x^2$. By simple observation, you can see that the function actually gets steeper the farther you go in the x direction. So it turns out that the slope actually increases. If you take data points for the slope, you will find that the slope actually increases by 2 for every x value you move to the right. This comes from the derivative of $x^2$ which is $2x$. To explain more would probably be outside the scope of this particular question.
For the scope of solving simple problems with slope, you want to put the function in y=mx+b form and then m is the slope. If you have a graph or data already, just pick two arbitrary points and apply the formula slope = $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$ (Note that $\Delta x$ means change in $x$.) To check your understanding, see if you can show that the slope formula I just wrote is a necessary result of the y=mx+b form.